# How do you retrieve the X.509 certificate that was used to construct a X509AsymmetricSecurityKey?

Tags: c#, cryptography, wif, claims-based-identity

You can construct a [X509AsymmetricSecurityKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.x509asymmetricsecuritykey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from a [X509Certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instance using the X509AsymmetricSecurityKey(X509Certificate2) constructor; but can get the X509Certificate2 instance from the security key?

As a parallel example, the [InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.inmemorysymmetricsecuritykey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class exposes a [GetSymmetricKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.inmemorysymmetricsecuritykey.getsymmetrickey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method that can be used to retrieve the symmetric key.

I had hoped to see an equivalent method like *GetCertificate()* exposed by the X509AsymmetricSecurityKey class, but the closest method I see is GetAsymmetricAlgorithm(string algorithm, bool privateKey).

What I am really after is the ability to verify the digital signature of a message that was signed using the private key of the certificate, which means the signature is verified using the public key of the certificate.

Is there a way to verify the signature using the asymmetric algorithm of the security key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While owlstead was correct that you cannot retrieve the X.509 certificate from the security key; what I should have indicated was that I was attempting to verify a digital signature of a JSON web token where the security key contained the public portion of the public-private key pair.

You can in fact use the security key to verify the signature. The following is an example of how to generally go about it:

```
var data        = {Get data that was signed as an array of bytes}
var signature   = {Get signature as an array of bytes}

// key variable is of type X509AsymmetricSecurityKey

using(var rsa = key.GetAsymmetricAlgorithm(SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, false) as RSACryptoServiceProvider)
{
    if(rsa != null)
    {
        using(var halg = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            if (!rsa.VerifyData(data, halg, signature))
            {
                throw new SecurityException("Signature is invalid.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you construct X509AsymmetricSecurityKey out of an X509Certificate2, the certificate instance reference is actually placed inside a private property named **certificate** on the key instance.

Your own answer satisfies your specific use case but not your question, the real answer to your question is:

> there is no direct way, but you can do it by using reflection.

```
X509AsymmetricSecurityKey x509Key = ...

X509Certificate2 cert = typeof(X509AsymmetricSecurityKey).GetField("certificate", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(x509Key) as X509Certificate2;
```

Comment: Note that using reflection like this results in code that is dependent on the *implementation* of the API and may therefore break anytime that implementation changes or differs (on e.g. different runtimes). It doesn't necessarily provide any forward compatibility for your application. Still, interesting hack :)

Answer (score 0):

`X509AsymmetricSecurityKey` is a component of `X509Certificate2`. You are asking if you can retrieve a car given a tire. X509 certificates contain a whole lot of additional information in addition to the public key stored within (issuer, serial number, key usage, effective date etc. etc.).

On the other hand, `InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey` does contain all the information of the symmetric key, so it is possible to retrieve the full key **data** using `GetSymmetricKey()`. Note that `GetSymmetricKey()` only returns a byte array, not a semantic object instance.

The only thing special about the Microsoft `X509Certificate2` is that it is linked with the private key, which is not part of the X509 data format. The private key and the public key in the certificate are part of the same key pair. That's why the private key can be thought of as part of the X509 certificate. They are also often stored together, e.g. in the PKCS#12 data format. Personally I think it only confuses matters.

If you want to link certificates with private keys then you can use the modulus of the key pair. It's identical for the private key and the public key. In some cryptographic standards they use a hash over the modulus to do this. So you can create a map from the hash over the modulus to a certificate. If you got a private key, retrieve the modulus, calculate the hash, and find the certificate.

Comment: I think the fact that Visar's *hack* works for me kind of contradicts this story.  Feel free to disagree.

Comment: @WillyVandenDriessche There doesn't seem to much to disagree about. It seems Microsoft thinks a key is part of a certificate and the other way around as well. Fine with me. But note that the hack only works if the field name never changes and when the certificate is always there for the key. A single change in the *implementation* of the API may break the (correctly identified) *hack*.

Comment: I'll leave my answer in case somebody decides to look up the certificate and play nice with the API, note that the answer of [Oppositional himself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12921906/589259) should be considered before any of the other answers (for his use case, anyway).

Comment: Ok, I'm not searching for a fight here.  Oppositional's scheme works if you seek to *validate* something.  In my case I was looking for the expiration date of the certificate so I can start yelling in the client application 3 months before actual expiry, buying devops some time to act on it.  I'm fully aware that calling private fields through reflection is hardly considered supported so my code has the necessary precautions to deal with that (I yell if the hack breaks too so at that moment *I* need to act).

Comment: @WillyVandenDriessche Me neither, I have upvoted the other answers. You are right in bringing this issue to me as the certificate does seem to be present (if not directly available through the API). It's just that I described the regular method of looking up certificates. My answer would certainly describe the way of least surprise to look up certificates for security professionals; if that wasn't the case I would have deleted my answer. But I'm fine with not getting any votes or accepts on it - or even some downvotes, my rep. can handle that I think :) I am contemplating an edit though.